# Ruby on Rails Active Record Attribute Introspection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to get the type of an attribute in Active Record (even before the attribute has been assigned)? For example (this doesn't work, just the goal):

```
User.new
User.inspect(:id)         # :integer
User.inspect(:name)       # :string
User.inspect(:password)   # :string
User.inspect(:updated_at) # :datetime
User.inspect(:created_at) # :datetime
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even without having an instance of the model you can use `Model.columns_hash` which is a hash of the columns on the model keyed on the attribute name e.g.

```
User.columns_hash['name'].type # => :string
User.columns_hash['id'].type # => :integer
User.columns_hash['created_at'].type # => :datetime
```

**Update**

As [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259900/kevin-sylvestre) has commented himself, if you have a model instance (e.g. `@user`) then the `column_for_attribute` method can be used e.g.

```
@user.column_for_attribute(:name) # => :string
```

From the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-column_for_attribute) you can see this is just a wrapper that calls `columns_hash` on the instance's class:

```
def column_for_attribute(name)
  self.class.columns_hash[name.to_s]
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! This lead to be to: `@user.column_for_attribute(:name).type`. Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Yep, if you have an instance of your model then `columns_for_attribute` is even better. I've updated the answer to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.type_for_attribute('attr_name') # ActiveModel::Type::Value
Model.attribute_types
```